# window.print() does not show more settings when I have the destination as Save as PDF

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

[image: Expected]

Expecting more setting option. But its not displaying.

Comment: I am just calling **window.print()**

Comment: working for me directly from console https://i.imgur.com/oEoNisa.png, as you can see print with pdf creator

Comment: Check out this link. https://ibb.co/3dV7q0k This is my problem. I am using Angular 6 with **MDB framework**

Comment: The print dialog is generated at the OS or browser level; it's not something you can control from within a web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the very late answer. The problem was with bootstrap. The more settings are not displayed because in bootstrap (v4) a specific CSS is applied.

```
@page {
  size: A4;
}
```

Due to this the more settings are not displayed.

Solution:-

```
@page {
  size: auto;
}
```

Write it in your CSS file to override it. Then it worked!!!